# Setting up Mariadb with Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo, laravel-5, mariadb

I've been trying to set up my database connexion to Laravel using MariaDB without success, executing my app return this error :

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 47:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'data'
```

here's my Database.php file:

```
'default' => 'mysql',

'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => storage_path().'/database.sqlite',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

    ],
```

Here's my .env file :

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=ZP9Ao5RJhZjS7EqJuaYRltSIC7HTL4vp

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=data
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
```

this error dump :

```
in Connector.php line 47
at PDO->__construct('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data', 'root', 'secret', array('0', '2', '0', false, '0')) in Connector.php line 47
at Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data', array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'data', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => 'secret', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql'), array('0', '2', '0', false, '0')) in MySqlConnector.php line 20
at MySqlConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'data', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => 'secret', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 58
at ConnectionFactory->createSingleConnection(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'data', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => 'secret', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 47
at ConnectionFactory->make(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'data', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => 'secret', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false), 'mysql') in DatabaseManager.php line 177
at DatabaseManager->makeConnection('mysql') in DatabaseManager.php line 65
at DatabaseManager->connection(null) in Model.php line 3134
at Model::resolveConnection(null) in Model.php line 3100
at Model->getConnection() in Model.php line 1895
at Model->newBaseQueryBuilder() in Model.php line 1836
at Model->newQueryWithoutScopes() in Model.php line 1810
at Model->newQuery() in Model.php line 3321
at Model->__call('get', array()) in SongsController.php line 20
at Song->get() in SongsController.php line 20
at SongsController->index()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(SongsController), 'index'), array()) in Controller.php line 246
at Controller->callAction('index', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 162
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(SongsController), object(Route), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 107
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 108
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(SongsController), object(Route), object(Request), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 67
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\SongsController', 'index') in Route.php line 198
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 131
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 693
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 660
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 210
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 111
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

I think it has to do with some sort of conflict between Mysql and MariaDB. It would be helpful if anyone who already tried to use MariaDB with Laravel could provide an example or experience.
The weird thing is I have been able to execute my migration file with "php artisan:migrate" and the database does exist with the appropriate tables. How can the migration scripts connect to the database and the controllers fail ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is your database name `data` or `forge`?

Comment: it's named data, I can see in the error dump that it is trying to access it I think :
MySqlConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'data', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => 'secret', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 58

Comment: make sure the `data` database exists (I know, sounds stupid, but chek again). Also, try using a different driver like `mysqli`

Comment: I did, I just checked for the third time, the database is indeed updated with the new tables from my migration file too.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved that upset, since I was using Homestead, a laravel vagrant box to execute my website, the site was in fact trying to connect to an inner mysql located inside Homestead, and I was never going to reach MariaDB. I have still not figured how to use MariaDB within Homestead, but at least  I have narrowed the search now.